# Is windowing based on event time possible with Spark Streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, streaming, spark-streaming, dataflow

According to the Dataflow Model paper : A practical approach to balancing correctness, latency and cost in massive-scale, unbounded, out-of-order Data processing:

> MillWheel and Spark Streaming are both sufficiently scalable,
>   fault-tolerant, and low-latency to act as reasonable substrates, but
>   lack high-level programming models that make calculating event-time
>   sessions straightforward.

Is it always the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not.

To quote from https://dzone.com/articles/spark-streaming-vs-structured-streaming so as to save on my lunch time!:

> One big issue in the streaming world is how to process data according
>   to event-time.
>
> Event-time is the time when the event actually happened. It is not
>   necessary for the source of the streaming engine to prove data in
>   real-time. There may be latencies in data generation and handing over
>   the data to the processing engine. There is no such option in Spark
>   Streaming to work on the data using the event-time. It only works with
>   the timestamp when the data is received by the Spark. Based on the
>   ingestion timestamp, Spark Streaming puts the data in a batch even if
>   the event is generated early and belonged to the earlier batch, which
>   may result in less accurate information as it is equal to the data
>   loss.
>
> On the other hand, Structured Streaming provides the functionality to
>   process data on the basis of event-time when the timestamp of the
>   event is included in the data received. This is a major feature
>   introduced in Structured Streaming which provides a different way of
>   processing the data according to the time of data generation in the
>   real world. With this, we can handle data coming in late and get more
>   accurate results.
>
> With event-time handling of late data, Structured Streaming outweighs
>   Spark Streaming.